# Mysql возвращает значения по разному

Tags: java, mysql, sql, база-данных

День добрый уважаемые форумчане. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть у меня БД состоящая из 5 таблиц. В одной из таблиц хранятся повторяющиеся элементы. Есть такое поле как "Дата". Суть в том что поле дата имеет формат не "даты" а формат "строки". В моем приложение была разработана часть кода которая переводит текущую дату в строку и затем записывает ее в БД. Столкнулся с такой проблемой при попытке получить Максимальную дата с конкретной ID_Card, творится какой-то мрак. То запрос отрабатывает корректно и никаких проблем. То выкидывает что значений по условию не найдено.
Таблицы. Запрос и проблема приведены ниже.

```
 create table sale_sum
 (
ID_SALE int auto_increment
    primary key,
ID_CARD int not null,
ID_USER int not null,
BUY_SUM float not null,
CASHBEK_SUM float not null,
GIFT_SUM int null,
DATE_BUY varchar(10) not null,
COMMENT varchar(255) null,
constraint sale_sum_discountcard_ID_CARD_fk
    foreign key (ID_CARD) references discountcard (ID_CARD),
constraint sale_sum_users_ID_USER_fk
    foreign key (ID_USER) references users (ID_USER)
```

)

К этой таблице был написан следующий запрос.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_USER, DATE_BUY 
FROM sale_sum 
WHERE ID_CARD=? 
 AND DATE_BUY = ( SELECT date_format(( SELECT max(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_BUY,'%d.%m.%Y')) 
                                       FROM sale_sum), '%d.%m.%Y'));
```

Данный запрос должен вернуть ID_user и максимальную дату.
Исходные данные.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При id_card=1; Ничего нет

При id_card = 2; Ничего нет

При id_card = 3; 
Id_card  DATE_BUY
2        06.06.2018

Comment: `SELECT max(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_BUY,'%d.%m.%Y')) FROM sale_sum)` возвращает `06.06.2018` при любом `id_card`, ведь когда вы ищете максимум, вы не фильтруете по `id_card`. Далее всё просто: для `id_card` равных 1 и 2 нет записей с `DATE_BUY` равным `06.06.2018`, потому и результат пустой.

Comment: Павел спасибо большое, сам бы наверное не скоро заметил бы. Переделал запрос вот в такой вид. Все стало работать как часы!) Еще раз спасибо. SELECT DISTINCT ID_USER, DATE_BUY FROM sale_sum WHERE DATE_BUY =(SELECT date_format((SELECT max(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_BUY,'%d.%m.%Y')) FROM sale_sum where ID_CARD=?), '%d.%m.%Y'))